# Large Brackets Make Line Breaks too Small

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, math-operators, brackets

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
$\text{tr }(PQ)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=i}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^m
\left[\displaystyle\prod_{i=i}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^m\
\left(p_{ij}q_{ij}\right)\right]
\\\text{tr }(QP)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=i}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^m
\left[\displaystyle\prod_{i=i}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^m
\left(q_{ij}p_{ij}\right)\right]$
\end{document}
```

When I use something like this, the output looks nice, but the breaks between lines look too small due to the size of `\left[` and `\right]`:

[image]

Is there a way to add a bit of space between these lines, so `\left[` and `\right]` don't look like they are almost touching?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need at most `\displaystyle` per line but you are probably better off using `\[...\]` or an `equation` environment.

Secondly, to get the spacing right around operators rather than using `\text` it is better to use

\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

from the [amsmath package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). Next, I suspect that what you really want here is to put everything into an alignment enviroment such as the `align*` environment to give:

[image]

Notice that the `&`'s tell latex where to align the two equations.

Finally, and this is a personal preference, I don't like using `\left...\right` as I think that the operators are usually too large. Instead I use the `amsmath` `\big`, `\bigg`, `\Big`, `\Bigg` operators. Here is the complete code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\begin{document}

  \begin{align*}
  \tr(PQ)&=\sum_{i=i}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^m
      \Big[\prod_{i=i}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^m\ p_{ij}q_{ij}\Big]\\
  \tr(QP)&=\sum_{i=i}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^m
    \Big[\prod_{i=i}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^m q_{ij}p_{ij}\Big]
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\Bigl[` and `\Bigr]`, not just `\Big`. You may also mention ``\\[<length>]``